# 'Series' object has no attribute 'values_counts'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

When I try to apply the values_count() method to series within a function, I am told that 'Series' object has no attribute 'values_counts'.

```
def replace_1_occ_feat(col_list, df):
    for col in col_list:
        feat_1_occ = df[col].values_counts()[df[col].values_counts() == 1].index 
        feat_means = df[col].groupby(col)['SalePrice'].mean()
        feat_means_no_1_occ = feat_means.iloc[feat_means.difference(feat_1_occ),:]
        for feat in feat_1_occ:
            # Find the closest mean SalePrice
            replacement = (feat_means_no_1_occ - feat_means.iloc[feat,:]).idxmin()
            df.col.replace(feat, replacement, inplace = True)
```

However when running df.column.values_count() outside a function it works.

The problem occurs on the first line when the values_counts() methods is used.
I checked the pandas version it's 0.23.0.

Answer (score 29):

The function is `value_counts()`. Note only count is plural.